# How to clone a Bitbucket repository that already contains files, using Sourcetree?

Tags: repository, clone, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am trying to clone a Bitbucket repository that already contains folders & files in it, using Sourcetree.

When I try and do this, I get a message saying that I need to use an empty or new folder.

Is there a way to achieve this seemingly simple task?

Answer (score 2):

> message saying that I need to use an empty or new folder

... as **destination** of clone operation, regardless of the original repository at Bitbucket's side

Answer (score 0):

The error message is referring to your destination folder, not the source. Just create a new empty destination folder and point to that. The source folder should contain an existing project.

Also, make sure you do this on the "Clone Repository" tab.

Comment: I don't want to add it to an empty folder.

Comment: I don't know that you can do that, because GIT would then have to merge the files it is trying to clone with your existing files, as it is doing the cloning. A simple way to do what you want, is to clone to an empty directory, then merge the changes from your existing directory, commit changes, and push back to the repository. Then you can delete the original folder and won't have a duplicate.

Comment: that's an awful lot of hassle for such a simple task. Surely, the .git file that keeps track of a project, can analyse a directory that already exists. I can do this, easily, with Coldfusion [my server side language], so it should be a breeze for something like Git. I don't see what the big problem is? 
And for me, this is what I would logically wish to do as a default behaviour. I think this is maybe why so many newbie's get confused when setting up their first Git clone.